# Trouble with slideshow animation

Tags: html, css

I'm a developer with not much CSS experience. I want to create a pure CSS3 slideshow using two images. I found [some nifty code](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg3) for doing so, and I've implemented a very slight variation below (basically I just took out the `#cf3` id selector for `img .top`):

```
.slide {
    position:absolute;
}   

@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
    0% {
          opacity:1;

}           
45% {
    opacity:1;

}           
55% {       
    opacity:0;

}       
100% {  
    opacity:0;

}       

}

img.top {
    animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-direction: alternate;

}
```

The first image is defined as `<img class="slideshow top" src="img1.jpg">`. The second is the same except without the `"top"` class.

When I load the page, all of my other CSS works, but the animation is nowhere to be found. Anyone see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add vendor specific property names, [CSS3 animation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-animations-20130219/) is still a draft spec.

```
-webkit-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;

-moz-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-duration: 10s;
-moz-animation-direction: alternate;

-o-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
-o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-duration: 10s;
-o-animation-direction: alternate;

animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-direction: alternate;

/* and all the keyframes too */
@-webkit-keyframes cf3FadeInOut { ... }
@-moz-keyframes cf3FadeInOut { ... }
@-o-keyframes cf3FadeInOut { ... }
@keyframes cf3FadeInOut { ... }
```